# Conflict when editing new records in Access connected to PostgreSQL by ODBC

Tags: postgresql, odbc, microsoft-access

I have a setup with Microsoft Access 2010 as a front-end and PostrgreSQL server 9.5.12 running on Linux as a back-end. Windows PC has PostrgreSQL ODBC driver 
 version 10_02_0000 (currently latest) installed. The connection is Unicode-based, settings are default, with the exception of `Bool as char` disabled and `True is -1` enabled.

The problem I'm encountering is that new records being added from Access immediately become locked and cannot be modified/deleted afterwards. Error message is: `Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time.`

I'm definitely the only one accessing the database, and I can modify/delete older records without any issues. The issue only happens for records that I create myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088970/ms-access-odbc-with-postgresql-table-write-conflict

My problem was caused by a `timestamp` field that had `default now()` constraint. Because timestamp in PostgreSQL by default has a higher precision compared to Access, automatic update via internal function `now()` caused a conflict due to mismatched values. Reducing precision in database by using `timestamp(0)` instead of just `timestamp` solves the problem.